# How do I generate a cancel button in simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I want to generate a cancel button using simple_form....but not quite sure how to do that.

```
<%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-warning btn-small", :label => "Save Changes" %>
<%= f.button :cancel, :class => "btn btn-inverse btn-small", :label => "Cancel" %>
```

But the cancel button doesn't work.

How do I get that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Should this be supported by simple form? I had a quick look at github and did not find anything related.

How about `link_to "Cancel", :back` ?

Comment: If you really need a button, make another :submit button and give it a name attribute of "cancel". Then you can check in the controller if params[:cancel] exists, and do a `redirect_to :back` from there.

Comment: but button :submit gets translted by I18n to "Submit #{model}"
but for Cancel there is no translation !

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with bootstrap easily.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create Plan</button>
<%= link_to "Cancel", :back, {:class=>"btn btn-default"} %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using simple_form and erb:

```
<%= f.submit, 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<%= f.button 'Cancel', type: :reset, class: 'btn btn-none' %>
```

Doing this does **not** take you to the previous page, it resets the form to its initial state.

Comment: It did not work, to much args here, with Rails 6.1, but this yes:
> f.button('Reset', type: :reset)

Comment: @HoZong tnx, updated

Answer (score 1):

Or since Rails 3:

```
link_to "Cancel", @foo
```

where `@foo` is your new or existing model object.  Depending on which it is, this link takes you to either `edit` or `new`.

Comment: Better to access the model object from the form, with form.object, specially if used in a helper, so no need to pass it: link_to("Cancel", form.object)

Answer (score 0):

You can use as `<%= button_tag "Cancel", :type => 'reset' %>`